# Why is this differential equation always a constant?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I'm reading [this PDF](http://www.alternatievewiskunde.nl/QED/normal.pdf?fbclid=IwAR0x2RAjmv0Xar50bNh_zuWOvLEhHHyusXCZooJajRCh7dMuNlhVhPN45uw) regarding a derivation of Normal Distribution and came across this statement:

*This differential equation is true for any x and y, and x and y are independent. That canonly happen if the ratio defined by the differential equation is a constant*

This is regarding this specific expression: $\displaystyle \frac{p'(x)}{xp(x)} = \frac{p'(y)}{yp(y)}.$

I'm a bit rusty on differential equations, but I'd like to know why this is true and is there any proof for it?

Comment: How else can $f(x) = f(y)$ $\forall x, y \in \text{Dom}(f)$ unless $f$ is constant?

Comment: Sure, viewing it that way made it more obvious, but how would you prove it?

Comment: Proof: assume $f(x)=f(y)=c(x,y)$ and take partial derivatives.

Comment: So your point is basically, $\displaystyle \frac{\partial f(y)}{\partial x} = 0$ and therefore a constant?

Comment: No. My point is that $\partial_x c=\partial_yc\equiv 0\,.$ Therefore ?

Comment: I don't really understand the difference. If I take the partial derivative $f_x(x)$ with respect to $x$, that would be the same as $f_x(y) = 0$ as $f(x) = f(y)$, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called the principle of separation of variables: if $f: X\rightarrow R$ and $g: Y\rightarrow R$  are such that for all $(x,y)\in X\times Y$ we have $f(x)=g(y)$ then there exists $C\in R$ such that $f(x)=C$ for all $x\in X.$ Proof: fix $y_0\in Y$ and take $C=g(y_0).$

Comment: Thank you for a clear answer!